# My tableview all of a sudden stopped scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, debugging, scroll

I'm not quite sure what I did, but not only can I not scroll. I can't select any items in my table. It's as if my table is disabled, but I'm sure it's not, at least I'm pretty sure.

Included is my code, which works, however there might be something I'm not noticing. But again, I didn't change anything.

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
@IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var searchResults = [String]()

@IBAction func cancelPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 18.0/255, green: 163.0/255, blue: 255.0/255, alpha: 1)
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return searchResults.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


    myCell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    myCell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lato", size: 18)
    myCell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    myCell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0



    return myCell
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    var textSearchQuery = PFQuery(className: "Go")
    textSearchQuery.whereKey("text", containsString: searchBar.text)

    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([textSearchQuery])

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
        {
            (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil
            {
                //var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.self)
                //let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
                //myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                //self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }

            if let objects = results as? [PFObject]
            {
                self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                for object in objects
                {
                    let searchText = object.objectForKey("text") as! String
                    self.searchResults.append(searchText)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                    {
                        self.myTable.reloadData()
                        self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
                }
            }
    }
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchBar.text = ""
}
}
```

Also, just a tiny issue I'm noticing, Word-wrapping isn't working. Anyway. So yeah, this is my problem. It used to scroll and now it doesn't. No clue why.

[image]

Comment: user interaction disabled?

Comment: Alright. I could have sworn that was on. So sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable user Interaction from Attribute inspector like shown into below image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Any clue about the issue with word wrapping?

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that the bottom of the original question, but I figured since I'd post the exact same code and image I wouldn't make a new question.

Comment: Please make a new question with more detail and specific code then.

Comment: Sure. I'll do that now. Hopefully you'll see it.

Comment: Sure and don't forget to accept this answer if it helps.. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have to wait an hour and a half to post a new question. Sigh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87221/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-james-chen).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I could have sworn that user interaction was enabled, but I guess not. Thanks for pointing it out. Sigh. One of those days.